# Are VS Code Extensions also free for commercial use?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the FAQ page of VS Code, there is a clear answer that VS Code itself is free for commercial use.
But, are VS Code "Extensions" also free for commercial use?

When I just look over the Marketplace, each Extension is made by a different person/team/company. Therefore, it seems that not all extensions are free for commercial use. (Maybe it depends on the publisher)

Then, how can I check if Extensions are free or not?

More specifically, are "Python"(by Microsoft) and "Python for VSCode"(by Thomas Haakon Townsend) free for commercial use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode extensions are considered as "open source" projects, so each one of them would have its own license. Both Microsoft's [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/LICENSE) and Thomas Haakon's [Python-vscode](https://github.com/tht13/Python-vscode/blob/master/LICENSE) use MIT License, which allow commercial usage with no problems. Microsoft's new Python language server [pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) is not open source, but it allows the usage of any number of copies with Visual Studio or VSCode, according to their [license](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.vscode-pylance/license)

You can always read the license yourself, or visit [choose a license](https://choosealicense.com) to get a summary of widely used software licenses

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I should have written more clearly about Python by Microsoft. Sorry for this. What I mentioned about Python by Microsoft is marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python. This includes "Pylance". When I read the license for this, there are sentences like below:

Comment: "But the optional Pylance extension for Visual Studio Code is only available in binary form and it is not licensed under the MIT License. The Pylance extension for Visual Studio Code is licensed under a Microsoft proprietary license, the terms of which are available here: marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.vscode-pylance/…." Then, does this mean it can't be used for commercial use?

Comment: Well, pylance is free after all, so nothing stops you from using it. The only difference is that it's not open source (it uses some propriety features from Microsoft), so it has its own terms. According to [pylance's license](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.vscode-pylance/license), Section 1, you are free to use any number of copies with Visual Studio or VSCode

Comment: I've edited the answer to include Pylance as well

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)